# Laravel and Angularjs partials

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I have a fairly simple app that filters a list of products.

Laravel creates the JSON feed for the products that I am reading and outputting with Angular and Laravel returns a filtered list based on what a user selects in a detailed filter form.

I have a requirement now that as a user filters results that the URL is changed in the browser and if the copy and paste it or share the link that they will be able to see the same results when the visit the app.

To do this I'll need to create routes with Angular and make use of angular partials. From reading the angular docs and watching a few screencasts it seems I need to reference partials that are html files.

Since I'm doing this with Laravel I've been using a Laravel view for my main view and using angular template tags within it and that works fine. If I want to start using partials how should I go about this? Where do I put the partials and can I reference them in my main laravel view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide any samples of your views code?

You might find this helpful when working with Blade and Angular.js

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

If you could provide some code it would make it easier to help, I don't quite understand what you're attempting to do.

You should be able to use ng-include anywhere in your Blade view.

You can use $location to change the URL, though I'm not sure how it will handle a lot of changes in quick succession.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tracked down my issue. I wasn't including angular-route.js so the partial weren't working as a result.

Comment: No problem. I once spent over 6 hours trying to track down why a directive(headroom.js) worked with jQuery and pure javascript but would not work as an angular directive. Thought it was a bug in the directive, tried fixing it, put in a bug report etc. Low and behold...I had never included it in my dependencies in angular.